# Connecting a PDF file to a DataBase

Tags: database, pdf

I've been told it is possible to create PDF forms that save the input data on a database. For example I create a form like this and send it to my work group, they compile it and all the data in the form is automatically saved into a database. Is that really possible? Does anybody have pointers to tutorials on how to do that? I googled a bit but I couldn't find useful info.

Thanks

Comment: http://answers.acrobatusers.com/Write-PDF-fields-database-q2300.aspx

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/6287/save-pdf-file-in-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: Why does it have to be PDF? Why not a simple html form?